# Which one is correct はらぺこにも見えない or はらぺこのようにも見えない？

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> へとへとにも、はらぺこにも、のどがからからにも、びくびくしているようにも見えなかった。

I try to reduce the sentence using the same end structure and using はらぺこ only which is a noun according to the dictionary. Which one is correct?

Comment: But if you reduce the sentence like that, も would take on a different nuance.

Comment: @aguijonazo No the meaning remains the same.

Comment: @vdegenne - In the original sentence も works as “neither” for each of the attributes listed. If only はらぺこ is left, も could be understood as “not even” or “not quite”, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine.

Basically にみえる and ようにみえる correspond to *look/look like*, but here it does not make much difference.

- 彼は外国人にみえる He looks a non-Japanese
- 彼は外国人のようにみえる He looks like a non-Japanese.

---

はらぺこ is grammatically a noun or a na-adjective, but either can be used in this pattern. See [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-ni-mieru-meaning/), for example.